# Error when trying to open my Preview in Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

iam working with swiftui for the first time. iam trying to make a small social network app, so i created a navigation bar which lays over the other views to navigate between them. But when iam trying to creat a Preview a Problem screen pops up, when iam running the app in the simulator everything work fine. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igZ4l.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFUhb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3YEx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHdu4.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Comment: This exact question has been asked many times you have to inject the environment object in the previous view https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NavigationBar view needs to receive an `@EnvironmentObject`, also from the preview.

Inside your `NavigationBar_Previews`, add one more modifier to the view, like this:

```
NavigationBar()
    .environmentObject(AppInformation())   // Add all initialisers necessary
                                           // to create the instance of AppInformation()
```